# LSTM: choice of batch size when State reused for generation later

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

I am building an LSTM model that generates symbols step-by-step. The task is to train the model up to some point of the data sequence and then to use the trained model to process the remaining pieces of the sequence in the test phase -- these remaining pieces weren't seen during Training.

For this task, I am attempting to re-use the latest state from the Training phase for the subsequent Prediction phase (i.e. not to start predicting with clean zero-state, but to sort-of continue where things were left off during training).

In this context, I am wondering how to best choose the Batch size for training.

My Training data is one long sequence of time-ordered observations. If that sequence is chopped up into N batches for Training, then my understanding is that the State tensor will be of shape `[N, Network_Size]` during Training, and `[1, Network_Size]` during Prediction. So for Prediction, I simply take the last element of the `[N, Network_Size]` tensor, which is of shape `[1, Network_Size]`.

That seems to work in terms of mechanics, but this means that the value of `N` determines how many observations that last vector of the original State has seen during Training.

Is there a best practice for determining how to chose N? The network trains much faster with a larger batch size, but I am concerned that this way the last part of the State tensor may have not seen enough. Obviously I'm trying various combinations, but curious how others have dealt with it.

Also, I have seen a few examples where parameters like this (or Cell size/etc.) are set as powers-of-2 (i.e. 64, 128, etc.). Is there any theoretical reason behind that vs simple 50/100/etc.? Or just a quirky choice?

Answer (score 1):

First, for your last question: for computers powers of two are simpler than powers of 10 (memory size and alignment constraints, for example, are likelier to be powers of two).

It is unclear from your question what you mean by training; if updating parameters or just computing RNN forward steps. Updating parameters doesn't make much sense because for RNNs (including LSTMs) you'd ideally update parameters only after seeing an entire batch of sequences (and you often need many updates until the model is at all reasonable). Similarly, RNN forward steps don't make much sense to me because the state for each example is independent of the batch size (ignoring any batch normalization you might be doing).

Comment: Suppose I have this data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]. If I choose batch size 2, then I have [1,2,3,4,5,6] and [7,8,9,10,11,12] and I can for example start training by passing sequences of length 3 to the network, so [1,2,3] and [7,8,9] in step 1 and [4,5,6] and [10,11,12], and so on (if the data were longer). On the other hand, if I chose batch size 3, then I have [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], and [9,10,11,12]. So if I start training on sequences of 3, then the last element of the State (the one that starts from 9) will have seen fewer observations during training than in the example with batch of 2

Comment: So if I then re-use the State for predictions after Training, then I can try to take the element of the State tensor as the State that remembers the last section of observations from the training data. So seems like the higher the batch size, the fewer observations that State portion will have seen. that's what I'm wondering about, if that makes any sense?

Comment: No, the batch size is completely orthogonal to the sequence length.